# How to pass closure as a parameter in perform(selector, withObject)

Tags: swift

I am trying pass closure as a parameter to swift and execute it in selector method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let closure = {
        print(self.isCityChoosen)
    }
    perform(#selector(foo(param:)), with: closure)
}

@objc func foo(param: () -> () ) {
    param()
}
```

But i have

`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)` 
Error in runtime when executing param()
Why does this error occur? 
Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your closure is not an Objective-C block, so it can't be passed through the ObjC runtime. You have to mark it as a block using `@convention`.

```
let closure: @convention(block) () -> Void = { ... }
```

You can convert an existing closure into a block by assigning it:

```
let closure = { ... }
let block: @convention(block) () -> Void = closure
perform(#selector(foo(param:)), with: block)
```

Objective-C blocks are actually objects, and participate in ARC. The crash occurs because `perform` tries to call `Block_copy` on a non-block.

Of course, as a rule selectors are not the right tools in Swift, and you should convert any selector-based interface to just take a function argument in the first place. If you find yourself using `perform`, you're probably on the wrong road in Swift. But it is still available if you need it.

Comment: Great, I didn’t know about convention attribute!

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason of using `perform(_:with:)`? If not, you can simplify your code and just call your method with closure

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    foo {
        print(self.isCityChoosen)
    }
}

func foo(param: () -> () ) {
    param()
}
```

Comment: i want to object that responds to selector call param() when he need it

Comment: @TrueHekka where exactly do you need this? Can't you avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's because you're using a non objective-c type in the method declaration:

`@objc func foo(param: () -> ())` the closure is not an objective-c type.

You can do something like this;

```
@objc func foo(_ closure: Any) {
    if let closure = closure as? () -> Void {
        closure()
    }
}
```

It works because (I guess) you tell the objc runtime that the method accepts `Any` which is correctly translated into objective-c type `id`.