# How to pass block arguments through performSelector?

Tags: swift

Im trying to use `performSelector` method to dispatch function and pass a block as arguments.

```
import Foundation

class SomeClass: NSObject {
    @objc func foo() {
        print("foo...")
        let selectorName = "bar:"
        let selector = Selector(selectorName)
        if self.responds(to: selector) {
            let block = { () in
                print("block")
            }
            self.perform(selector, with: block) //this will crash
//            self.bar(block) //this will be ok
        }
    }
    
    @objc func bar(_ arg1: @escaping ()->()) {
        print("bar...")
        arg1()
    }
}

let someClass = SomeClass()
someClass.foo()
```

**As the sample code showed, It will crash  when use `self.perform(selector, with: block)`. And my question is how can i pass the block arguments through `performSelector` ?**

Comment: Why? What are you really trying to achieve? This is a very unSwifty approach to solving a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for `perform` it says:

This method is the same as perform(_:) except that you can supply an argument for aSelector. aSelector should identify a method that ***takes a single argument of type id***.

`id` is a pointer to an objective-c object. From Swift, you are going to be limited to passing objects that inherit from NSObject. A closure does not meet those requirements. If you must, you can do something like so:

```
class Block: NSObject {
    let block: () -> Void
    init(block: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.block = block
    }
}

class SomeClass: NSObject {
    @objc func foo() {
        print("foo...")
        let selectorName = "bar:"
        let selector = Selector(selectorName)
        if self.responds(to: selector) {
            let block = Block {
                print("block")
            }
            self.perform(selector, with: block)
        }
    }

    @objc func bar(_ arg1: Block) {
        print("bar...")
        arg1.block()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  And i find a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55340270/how-to-pass-closure-as-a-parameter-in-performselector-withobject.